# CodeIgniter : 3.0 database migration through composer

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-migration, codeigniter-3

Iam working on CodeIgniter database Migrations.
I create table using **Migrate.php** controller in my project and it's work fine.

> **Question**  is it possible to migrate database using cmd like laravel database Migrations?.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> **You can do it with `php index.php tools`**

[image]

> Most frameworks have built-in command lines and almost all users of these frameworks have to interact with the command line. **CodeIgniter has the base for the command line interface but it’s not implemented by default**.

[image: 01]

Go through with this tutorial [CodeIgniter Migration - tutorials.kode-blog.com](http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/codeigniter-migration)